# What does the modcount variable when debugging the collection

Tags: java, eclipse, collections

When debugging Java code using Eclipse, for collection variables, I saw the `modcount` member.  What does it mean?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Many of Java's collections produce iterators that are "fail-fast", which means that if the collection is changed after an iterator is created, the iterator will be invalidated and throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` as soon as it can.  (As compared to failing later or returning invalid data.)

In order to support this functionality, the collection has to keep track of whether it has been modified.  Each time the collection is changed, it increments `modcount`.  When the collection produces an iterator, the iterator stores the value of `modcount` from when it was created.  Then whenever you try to use the iterator, it checks to see if its saved `modcount` is different from the parent collection's current `modcount`; if it is, the iterator fails with a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

(An exception to this rule is that modifications to the collection made through the iterator itself (like the iterator's `remove` method) do not invalidate the iterator.)

Comment: thanks for this really good explanation. I knew it did something like this, but not detailed

Comment: Very good explanation. It now makes sense.

Comment: code : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ListItr